# Tensorflow: Cannot import user_ops from my python file

Tags: operation, tensorflow

I have run the tutorials and created my own neural network implementation in tensorflow successfully.  I then decided to go one bit further an add my own op because I needed to do some of my own preprocessing on the data.  I followed the tutorial on the tensorflow site to add an op.  I successfully built tensorflow after writing my own c++ file.  Then, when I try to use it from my code, I get

```
'module' object has no attribute 'sec_since_midnight'
```

My code does get reflected in bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_user_ops.py so the wrapper does get generated for it correctly.  It just looks like I can't see the    tensorflow/python/user_ops/user_ops.py which is what imports that file.

Now when I when I go through the testing of this module, I get the following odd behavior.  It should not pass because the expected vector I give it does not match what the result should be.  But maybe the test never gets executed despite saying passed?

```
INFO: Found 1 test target...
Target //tensorflow/python:sec_since_midnight_op_test up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/sec_since_midnight_op_test
INFO: Elapsed time: 6.131s, Critical Path: 5.36s
//tensorflow/python:sec_since_midnight_op_test              (1/0 cached) PASSED

Executed 0 out of 1 tests: 1 test passes.
There were tests whose specified size is too big. Use the --test_verbose_timeout_warnings command line option to see which ones these are.
```

Comment: I am struggling right now with importing my own custom op as well... Can you, please, tell how exactly you were importing it? And what changes should be reflected in 'bazel-genfiles/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_user'?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Well, I uninstalled tensorflow and then I reinstalled from what I just built and what I wrote was suddenly recognized.  I have seen this behavior twice in a row now where an uninstall is necessary.  So to sum, the steps after adding my own op are:

```
$ pip uninstall tensorflow
$ bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

# To build with GPU support:
$ bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg

# The name of the .whl file will depend on your platform.
$ pip install /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-0.5.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```